# Training Autoencoder Latent space with custom properties

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder, encoder-decoder

I trained an autoencoder with 16 latent dimensions on an input of 21*18 matrix and it worked well. However the latent space is not in my control as in, I cannot have each node represent a property i want it to represent.

I was looking for **ideas and approaches to allow me to optimize each node in latent space with a seperate desired property** , while also making sure the reconstruction on the decoder side for the matrix is optimized.

Any help is appreciated.

The end goal is that I want to remove the decoder after training, Provide it with values for each node, and get a corresponding prediction of 21*18 matrix for those input properties

Comment: Have you heard of a Variational Autoencoder and "Disentangling the latent space"?

Comment: Do you mean using Conditional VAE for the problem?.

Comment: Not necessarily. Just VAE generally

Comment: I would need more help understanding the use of Disentangling Latent Space for the problem at hand. Can you point me to resources that are able to achieve node level property optimizations?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Yoan-D/disentangled-VAE) is an example

Comment: Thank you. But This is not what i was looking for. What I meant is lets say i have 16 latent nodes. Now I also have 16 different known regressive properties(like speed, force, momentum etc...)which i want each node to optimize for while also reconstructing the input .

The end goal is that I want to remove the decoder after training, Provide it with values for each node, and get a corresponding prediction of 21*18 matrix for those input properties

Comment: Yes I know what you mean ;) the dsprites dataset has the properties: Color: white
Shape: square, ellipse, heart
Scale: 6 values linearly spaced in [0.5, 1]
Orientation: 40 values in [0, 2 pi]
Position X: 32 values in [0, 1]
Position... but if you say so ;)

Comment: Yes, Youre right, But I cannot optimize each node in hidden layer with specific property instead of letting model come up with its own representations for hidden nodes? 

The Output that I am looking for will be the same, but i want to optimize z1 to represent speed, z2 to represent momentum etc

Comment: Why should it not be possible?

Comment: In the repo you have shared, he/she is manually modifying z1...z9 for given target property(square representation in matrix), with no specific training for z1 to represent scale, z2 to represent shape etc etc.

In my case I want to make the model learn that z1 is speed so it would represent any changes about speed only, z2 for force etc..

Comment: Of course you can hard code that z1 should represent a scale etc. (and there is a lot of literature on this topic) but actually you want your model to identify and semantically separate these properties by itself. You also want it to figure out how some of these properties relate to each other

Comment: Can you point me to some literature around that? 

If model identifies these properties, during inference, how do we know what node to be provided with what property right?

Comment: Yeah you could control that aspect with some kind of metadata (labels)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239022/discussion-between-aditya-vartak-and-alonetogether).